# How to set APM service name in DataDog for an application using Nodejs

Tags: datadog

I am not able to see traces for my application under APM --> Service in Datadog. I found some sample code from Datadog docs but don't know exactly where it should go inside my application. Please let me know if anyone has any idea regarding it.

I have already tried with following code in my js file. My application is based on node js which is serverless.

```
const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();
tracer.use('http', {
    service: 'test'
});
```

I have also added dependencies for dd-trace in package.json as `"dd-trace": "^0.11.0"`

I expected to list my application with proper name in APM Services in Datadog.

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing is correct only, however, the common mistake is not following the below.

> This library MUST be imported and initialized before any instrumented
>   module. When using a transpiler, you MUST import and initialize the
>   tracer library in an external file and then import that file as a
>   whole when building your application. This prevents hoisting and
>   ensures that the tracer library gets imported and initialized before
>   importing any other instrumented module.

Basically, you cannot have `require(any instrumented lib)` (e.g. http, express, etc) before calling init() tracing function.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup/nodejs/